# HTTP streaming on android

Tags: android

I'm wondering if it's possible to do http streaming on android, a http url like : https://rutube.ru/video/9e244625fcbb673cb0ba5db66c683a5f

So in my app I can click on a button and I have the video player that show me the video?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to play the video in a video player that is already installed , or you want to develop a player which decodes the stream and play the video inside ?

Comment: I want to play the video in the default video player of my smartphone, but its a great idea to develop my owne video player :) u have an idea or a topic that can help me ? :)

Answer (score 0):

RuTube doesn't provide link to url as I know. You posted link to webPage, not to a video. If you will gain direct link to video, then you can play This video with MediaPlayer and VideoSurface. But you need to have direct link and video must have compability format.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ah yes sorry it's an error I mean a direct link to the video like the stuff of iframe in html :) it's possible to play it in the default player of my smartphone ?

Comment: I don't think, that you can get direct link.  It plays video with FlashPlayer and I don't know how to get direct link on that page. Therefore, it's easy to play video on default video player. Look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information :) there is a solution like to decode the video, so I can play it on the default video player like they do in some application like the app : Downloader

Comment: I tested the code that you give in your answer earlier but I have the error : The video is not compatible

Comment: This mean, that you provide link contains non copatible video or even not contains video at all.

Comment: Hmm ok :) and for the think of decoding the video so I can play it on the defaut video player of the smartphone, it's possible ? :)